# Multiple Queries in MS SQL Update query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have an update query in which the where clause contains multiple queries, thus:

```
UPDATE Table 'tableA'
SET    FieldA = 'Y'
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID
              FROM   tabA)
        OR ID IN (SELECT ID
                  FROM   tabB)
```

Ok, the query above is just a quick example of the query I have, but my question is that I have another field to set in 'tableA' whose value depends upon which of the two queries executes in the where clause. For example if Select ID from tabA returns, then I want to set a value, say in FieldB = 'First Query'.

So, is there a way of setting a local variable against each query which I can pass to the set clause, or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: What if both of them match or do you know for a fact that this is impossible?

Comment: Both queries will not be satisfied at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set it as a variable in php (or whatever you use)? and then include the variable in the query?

```
$query = "= 'Y' WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID from tabA) OR ID IN (SELECT ID from tabB)";
"UPDATE tableA SET FieldA = " . $query . ", SET FieldB = " . $query . "";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no because this update query runs on a database as part of an extract process that runs over night. So, I need to know which of the queries runs in order to set a value. The only easy solution is to have lots of separate update queries, which to me looks poor

Comment: Hmm think this was not quite what you wanted...I got it after your comment above...

Comment: Hi! I have managed to crack this by adding in a case statement into the set part of the update query and it works. So, solved my own problem